# How to dynamically define project root path in config file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fb-hydra

I want to define project root path in Hydra config file without hardcoding it. 'til now couldn't find any feature of Hydra that can imply the path!

E.g., suppose we have the following project structure:

```
project-name
├── conf
│   ├── config.yaml
│   ├── config.py 
├── src
│   ├── model.py
```

Now I want to define the project path in `config.yaml` up to `project-name`. For example `project_path: C:\\Projects\\project-name`. However, instead of hardcoding `C:\\Projects\\`, I want Hydra to figure out for me what the preceding path is up to and including `project-name`.

With python I can do something in `config.py` like:

`str(Path(__file__).parent.parent.absolute())`

However, I want to get rid of `config.py`, and do all the configurations in `config.yaml`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by Hydra. The concept of a root directory is not defined well enough.
You can use OmegaConf [custom resolvers](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.2_branch/custom_resolvers.html) to implement your on logic on a specific node but it's not clear to me how you can achieve what you are trying to do in a clean and reusable way.

Comment: this is all implicit. I want to define the path in YAML file like `${hydra:runtime.cwd}` but then for the project root path.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. project "root path" can mean about a million things.

Comment: I have updated the question description. Please see the example.

Comment: hydra.runtime.cwd is managed by Hydra itself. Do you want to get the parent of that directory from your config file?

Comment: I want to get the project directory; parent cwd doesn't ensure the root directory. A script could be executed from any depth in the project.